# Make disabled QRadioButton look enabled python

Tags: python-2.7, pyside, qradiobutton

I am trying to make disabled QRadioButtons look Enabled. I want them to look normal, but not allow the user to change them. I tried QRadioButton.setCheckable(False) and then setting QRadioButton.setChecked(True). As can be assumed, QRadioButton.setChecked(True) doesn't work, as it is overruled by setCheckable. How can I go about this, so that programatically, I can set the radiobutton as checked, but the user can't change it?

I tried QPalette like such:

```
pal = self.SearchPastDB.missingFood.palette()
pal.setColor(QPalette.Disabled, QPalette.Text, pal.color(QPalette.Active, QPalette.Text))
pal.setColor(QPalette.Disabled, QPalette.Base, pal.color(QPalette.Active, QPalette.Base))
self.SearchPastDB.poorQual.setPalette(pal)
self.SearchPastDB.wrongFood.setPalette(pal)
self.SearchPastDB.missingFood.setPalette(pal)
```

I have also tried:

```
pal = QPalette()
pal.setColor(QPalette.Disabled, QPalette.Text, pal.color(QPalette.Active, QPalette.Text))
pal.setColor(QPalette.Disabled, QPalette.Base, pal.color(QPalette.Active, QPalette.Base))
self.SearchPastDB.poorQual.setPalette(pal)
self.SearchPastDB.wrongFood.setPalette(pal)
self.SearchPastDB.missingFood.setPalette(pal)
```

This didn't work either, so I feel I might have done that wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the QRadioButton stylesheet disabled same as enabled..just put

```
QRadioButton{_YOUR_STYLESHEET_}

QRadioButton::disabled{_YOUR_STYLESHEET_}
```

Same for `QRadioButton::indicator` to give it the same enabled style